# Immutable js how to get specific value in complex structure

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a Immutable Map in structure as below.

[Immutable Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9TyB.png)

In this map there is specific array with value "filterOptions". Under it, there is maps with arrays. Inside this array, first index is value and second index with specific value like "CMS". Reference from the picture structure, I would like to gather this value such as CMS, MOBILE and etc as return of Immutable map.
How can I do this?

I tried as below and I get error undefined map. Please help

```
const filterLevel1AvailableLots= filterLevel1.get('filterOptions').map(option => {
    return Immutable.Map({option: option})});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just want `filterLevel1.get('filterOptions').map(` not `.filter.map(`:

```js
var filterLevel1 = Immutable.Map({
  filterOptions: Immutable.List([
    Immutable.Map({value: 'CMS'}),
    Immutable.Map({value: 'Mobile'}),
  ])
});

var filterLevel1AvailableLots = filterLevel1
       .get('filterOptions')
       .map(option => Immutable.Map({option: option}));

console.log(filterLevel1AvailableLots);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.2/immutable.js"></script>
```

Comment: My apology, I had edited my post and you're right that I meant "filterLevel1.get('filterOptions').map(" , and this is what actually I tried that produced error map undefined for the Immutable map structure I provided.

Comment: @Venos Can you provide the actual map as code? The map I have in my answer is the same structure as the one you describe and screenshot and is working fine with just `map`.